# PrettyPhoto Ajax Content not loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, prettyphoto

I have a page being loaded in via Ajax, I want to have a lightbox for my youtube video, but everytime I reinitalize the prettyPhoto plugin it causes my page to freeze and break.

Here is my code:

```
$(".vidlist a").live("click", function(evt) {
     var page4 = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#page1").load(page4, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'dark_square'});
     });
     evt.preventDefault();
  });
```

And Here is my anchor tag

```
<a id="1" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0pCMVwwqOM" rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" title="Body language quirks">
    Body language quirks</a>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me or let me know why its crashing my page